# Dropping NaN rows doesn't work in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with about 7k rows and 4 columns. A lot of the cells are empty and I have tried to drop them using a number of pandas functions but nothing seems to work. Functions I have tried and the code are below:

What I have tried:

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

and

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

My code:

```
file = "pc-dirty-data.csv"
path = root + file
name_cols = ['GUID1', 'GUID2', 'Record ID', 'Name', 'Org Name', 'Title']
pull_cols = ['Record ID', 'Name', 'Org Name', 'Title']
df = df.dropna(thresh=2) 
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col=False)
df.info()
```

Dataframe:

```
RangeIndex: 6599 entries, 0 to 6598
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Record ID    5874 non-null float64
Name         5874 non-null object
Org Name     5852 non-null object
Title        5615 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)
```

Comment: Just use `df.dropna()` and see if that works. Applying threshold and how params will change the way the rows are dropped.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to drop before you read. Try: `df = pd.read_csv(...)`, then `df = df.dropna()`.

Comment: @Jay Wow... looks like I have been staring at the code for too many hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`dropna` is not an inplace operation, you need to reassign it back to the variable or use the `inplace` parameter set to True.

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

or

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
```

## Edit

Jay points out in the comments that, you need to reorder you code logic such that you dropna after the read_csv.

Comment: I get this when I trie AttributeError: 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'dropna'